# Getting the count of groups from a GROUP BY query - without using subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

As an example, I have a relation called STUDENT with the following attributes:

```
SID (primary key), NAME, FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
```

I want to retrieve how many times there are more than 10 students with the same FACULTY, AGE and MAJOR (these attributes are non-key and non-unique).

I'm able to write a query for this, but I don't want to be selecting from a subquery.

I have a solution to this which is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
   (SELECT FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, COUNT(*)
    FROM STUDENT
    GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10) students
```

This gets me the expected result, however I want to write a query that doesn't involve selecting from a subquery. Is there any alternative query to what I've given?

Comment: Your code is not selecting from a view, unless `student` is a view.  So, I don't understand the question.  If you are confusing a "view" with a *derived table*, then there really isn't a sensible way to do what you want without using one.

Comment: By "selecting from a view", I mean selecting from a select statement. Sorry if this is unclear; I see where the terminology I've used is incorrect. I'll edit the question now

Comment: Your query involves a _derived table_ (the FROM clause's sub-qeury), which is not the same thing as a view. (Even if some people call it inline view.)

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a subquery?

Comment: @jarlh It's not "some people" who call it an inline view. It's the Oracle documentation.  See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just thought that there might be a more elegant way of writing the query in question. Using nested aggregation was what I was looking for, but it seems that using a subquery provides more clarity to the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't really seem to be anything wrong with what you are doing; but you could do:

```
SELECT COUNT(COUNT(*))
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

That is, using nested aggregation; there's also an example of this [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html).

We don't have your data, so demo with the HR sample-schema employee table:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select department_id, count(*)
  from  employees
  group by department_id
  having count(*) > 5
);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

select count(count(*))
from employees
group by department_id
having count(*) > 5;

COUNT(COUNT(*))
---------------
              4
```

Having the subquery makes it a bit clearer what you are doing though.

---

You could also use subquery factoring I suppose, but as the name suggests that's still a subquery - whether you have the same objection to that is unclear though:

```
WITH students (FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, c) AS (
  SELECT FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, COUNT(*)
  FROM STUDENT
  GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students;
```

or

```
WITH students (FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, c) AS (
  SELECT FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, COUNT(*)
  FROM STUDENT
  GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
)
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students
WHERE c > 10;
```

Demo again:

```
with cte (departmenr_id, c) as (
  select department_id, count(*)
  from  employees
  group by department_id
  having count(*) > 5
)
select count(*)
from cte;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

with cte (departmenr_id, c) as (
  select department_id, count(*)
  from  employees
  group by department_id
)
select count(*)
from cte
where c > 5;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4
```

You don't actually need `FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR,` in the subquery, in either form (your original or using a CTE) since you don't use them outside; you can group by expression you don't select.

Answer (score 2):

What if you simply append the count to your result set? Seems like you're trying to count how many rows of data you have in your result set.

```
SELECT FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR, COUNT(*), COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

If you only need the count, you could do

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY FACULTY, AGE, MAJOR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

Comment: The expected result seems to be just one final number; so you could do `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER ()`. That seems even less intuitive than `SELECT COUNT(COUNT(*))` to me though. Interesting approach though.

Comment: @AlexPoole I agree 100%. I only added this approach to show that having them side by side is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
select count(distinct facultry || ':' || age || ':' || major)
from student s1 join
     student s2
     on s1.faculty = s2.faculty and
        s1.age = s2.age and
        s1.major = s2.major an
        s1.sid < s2.sid join
     student s3
     on s1.faculty = s3.faculty and
        s1.age = s3.age and
        s1.major = s3.major an
        s2.sid < s3.sid join
     . . . 
     student s11
     . . .
```